# string[x] vs *string++

Tags: c

Which of the 2 methods is theoretically faster and why ? *(The pointer to string must be constant.)*

What is the exact difference between *destination[count]* and **destination++* ? Does *destination[count]* keep moving from *0* to *count* on every call ? Does **destination++* just add 1 on each call ?

```
char *const string = "Hello world!";
char *destination = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
int count = 0;
while(string[count] != '\0')
{
    destination[count] = string[count];

    count++;
}

char *const string = "Hello world!";
char *destination = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
char *ptr = string;
while(*ptr != '\0')
{
    *destination++ = *ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why should we speculate? We can try it and find out. I compiled the code with `gcc -O3 -g` (on x86) and disassembled the result. There were more changes than I expected, so I'll focus in on the bits in the middle where we'd expect the bulk of the differences between the two to be.
The core of the loop in the first case:

```
0x00000030 <foo+48>:    mov    %dl,(%edi,%esi,1)
0x00000033 <foo+51>:    movzbl 0x1(%ecx),%edx
0x00000037 <foo+55>:    inc    %eax
0x00000038 <foo+56>:    inc    %ecx
0x00000039 <foo+57>:    mov    %eax,%esi
0x0000003b <foo+59>:    test   %dl,%dl
0x0000003d <foo+61>:    jne    0x30 <foo+48>
```

The core of the loop in the second case:

```
0x00000080 <foo2+48>:   mov    %dl,(%eax)
0x00000082 <foo2+50>:   movzbl 0x1(%ecx),%edx
0x00000086 <foo2+54>:   inc    %eax
0x00000087 <foo2+55>:   inc    %ecx
0x00000088 <foo2+56>:   test   %dl,%dl
0x0000008a <foo2+58>:   jne    0x80 <foo2+48>
```

---

On that basis, the second is perhaps a little faster. But really, it won't make much difference in practice. The L1 cache holds both loops just fine and the target memory is uncached so the differences will be moot. Good luck with ever actually measuring a difference between the two.

Comment: Does less instructions == faster on x86?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: Not necessarily. It really depends on what those instructions are doing, since accessing main memory is far slower than running in L1 cache. As I noted, I'd expect the speeds to be *very* similar in practice (and the overall time of the function will actually be totally dominated by the call to `malloc`; that's hugely slower than the copy because it may involve a complex search or system call).

Comment: It depends.  Here are a couple of reasons why: Different instructions take different amounts of cycles to complete (and the instructions are different sizes).  Alignment of loops can have significant impact on speed (jumping 64 bytes is good, jumping 63 is less good).  Reducing the size of your code often speeds up code by better utilizing the intervening caches.  However, dependency chains and branch prediction are two strong predictors (better than instruction count or code size) of code performance.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, but when you've got a mix of code that fits all in the L1 icache and data that is at least partially uncached, it'll be the data access time that dominates; the processor will spend its time just waiting for the memory-bound data operations to happen. Since the data access pattern of the two snippets is the same (equivalent memory locations, same order) I would expect the time taken to be very similar indeed. And the `malloc` call *will* dominate.

Comment: hm.. In the first case, `gcc` want to preserve  `destination`, so it allocated `%esi` for that temp pointer. This is what make the extra instruction.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the compiler. With modern compilers it's really not possible to predict anything about optimization on the single-instruction level without actually looking at the generated code. Both probably compile to equivalent instructions.

That said, `destination[count]` does *not* loop from 0 to `count` on each call. It takes the memory location of `destination[0]`, adds `count` times the size of the type of `*destination`, and looks there. (This is all naively speaking, of course - the compiler probably does something faster.)

On the other hand, `*destination++` takes the memory location of `destination[0]` (which is *not* the beginning of the array anymore, since you've changed `destination`), looks there, and adds the size of the type of `*destination` so that `destination[0]` refers to what used to be `destination[1]`.

Answer (score 5):

In the good old days, the second method is faster. But with **the modern compiler optimization, they are just the same**.

This is because:

```
destination[count] = string[count];
```

would be doing

```
*(destination+count) = *(string+count);
```

It take two more `add` operation in each loop. Modern compiler would just do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the CPU. On a x86, the first version is slightly faster (or, at least, it will result in a slightly shorter code), because it only takes one instruction to load from string[count] and one instruction to write into destination[count]. So the pseudocode would look sort of like this (each line = one assembly instruction)

```
register = *(string+count) 
*(destination+count) = register
count += 1
compare register, 0
jump to line 1 if nonzero
```

and the second version would be

```
register = *ptr
*destination = register
ptr += 1
destination += 1
compare register, 0
jump to line 1 if nonzero
```

In practice, any optimizing compiler will optimize the heck out of this code, and, depending on its sophistication, the compiler may even be able to turn the first version into the second or vice versa. So there's no telling which one is going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

`*destination++` actually adds `sizeof(*destination)` at each call (it depends on the pointer size) while `destination[count]` should be doing `*(destination + count * sizeof(*destination))` but it's probably optimized by the compiler anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`destination[count]` is the *count*-th element (0 based) in `destination[]`. `count++` ensures that in each time the loop is entered, `destination[count]` is one past the last element accessed in previous iteration (except, of course, the first entrance).

`*destination++ = *ptr++;` is same as the following:

```
*destination = *ptr;
destination++;
ptr++;
```

Note that `destination++` increments the pointer value by `sizeof(*destination)`, which will point to next element in array, not the data pointed by `destination` (or `*destination`).

For modern compilers, both will be optimized to almost same binary, so it doesn't matter which one you choose with respect to speed.

Comment: Sorry, "Note that destination++ increments the pointer value by 1", actually adds `sizeof(*destination)`, which may not be 1

Answer (score 0):

If "string" arives as an argument in a function, you could use that as an iterator instead of "ptr". Then you'll have one less variable to hold on the stack. That could possibly mean that the compiler can keep all local variables in registers, and that would improve performance.

That of course depends, if the compiler manages to do away with "count" you wont get any performance increments.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from a high level, both operations involve a dereference and an addition.  The expression `destination[count]` is evaluated as `*(destination + count)`.  The expression `*destination++` is (most likely) evaluated as `*destination; destination += 1` (bearing in mind that the side effect only needs to be applied before the next sequence point, which is not necessarily immediately after the expression is evaluated).

So theoretically there shouldn't be that much difference between the two versions.  The only way to know *for your particular platform* is to code up both versions and compare their performance.